# Using a private Method with return

Tags: c#, return

I have recently start to practice c# and come across this problem:
I just want to save 'dataTaken' in 'public string date', so i can acces this variable directly.

```
class Bild
    {

        public int id;
        public String source;
        public string dataTaken;
        public string data;

        private string getAufnahmeDatum () {
            string dataTaken = [.....]this.source;
            return dataTaken;
            }

**//-> data = this.getAufnahmeDatum(); // dose not work.**

     }
```

I get some erros, trying this.

**date :** 'date' dose not exist in the current context

**getAufnahmeDatum:**

- Method must have an return type
- Bild.getAufnahmeDatum must declare a
  body because its not marked abstarct,extern or partial
- Type Bild already defines a memeber called getAufnahmeDatum with the same
  parameter typs

I find it curios that when I dont define public string dataTaken; i get an error too ( dose not exist in th current context).

I thought string dateTaken = [...] should be enough.

PS: Is there a trick to copy that damn erros out of VisualStudio ?

Comment: Are you using the not working call inside a method?

Comment: yes. I tried `data = this.getAufnahmeDatum()`;

Comment: Please try `public string data = getAufnahmeDatum();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get exactly these error messages if you write this code inside the class but not within a method!

```
// fails with the described error
data = this.getAufnahmeDatum();

// works without error
private void Test()
{
    data = this.getAufnahmeDatum();
}
```

You could for example call the code in the constructor of the class

```
public Bild()
{
    data = this.getAufnahmeDatum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in other way too by using `set`.

```
class Bild
{
    public int id;
    public String source;
    public string dataTaken;
    public string data
    {
        set { value = this.getAufnahmeDatum(); }
    }

    private string getAufnahmeDatum()
    {
        string dataTaken = this.source;
        return dataTaken;
    }
}
```

You can have `get` property also, if you want `data` to be `read/write`.